# Bug on site stats?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stats, beta-phase

**Update:** Seems like it's been fixed.

---

In the stats sidebar:

[image]

In the Area51 Stats section:

[image]

Is this a bug, or are 'visitors/day' different from 'visits/day'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the same visitor can visit the site multiple times, sure those are different things. But how 0 visitors manage to visite 3,402 times a day, you'll have to ask a magician – unless that's supposed to mean "there was no visitor accessing this site 3,402 times a day – everybody who visited had different numbers". Then it makes sense again :)

So I'd say: It's OK the numbers are differing. But at the same time, "0 visitors" looks like a bug – as I visit the site daily, and I think I'm not a zero :)

Comment: True, I was mainly pointing out the buggy 0 :) - but looks like it's been fixed now!

Comment: Ah, OK. Maybe they were just working on something, so that was a "temporary glitch in the Matrix" :)

Comment: lol. weird thing is it only happened on SR, not other beta sites (at least not code review - the only one I checked)

Comment: No idea what might be behind it. But most importantly, it's fixed :)